# IIS with ASP.NET Core application compiled with VS2017 is not running

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a REST-Webservice which I developed with Visual Studio 2015 as a "ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core 1.X) → Web API (No Auth per Default)" application and later upgraded my project to Core 2.0 with the first supported VS2017 version. Everything was working fine.

Now I got a new computer and I installed the latest Visual Studio 2017 on my machine.

Before when I published the application I received lots of "Microsoft.AspNetCore...dll" stuff which is included in "Microsoft.AspNetCore.All":

[image: Compiledstuff]

...more...

[image]

That's running great on my IIS webserver!

Now, with VS2017 the published stuff looks totally different:

[image]

When publishing that stuff I have more options, but none of that stuff is working.
Publish configuration (Filesystem):

- Targetframework: netcoreapp2.0
- Framework dependant (theoretically I prefer this)
- Standalone (this export way more dll's but is not working)
- Portable/win-x86/win-x64
- I tried all combinations, but none of this is working.

Of course I've installed "DotNetCore.2.0.7-WindowsHosting.exe" on the server.

This is the page I am getting in IIS as a result.

[image]

I also created a new empty "ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core 2.0)" project with a hello-world site. Even this page is not running on my IIS and shows the same error.

What am I doing wrong and how can I get a result like in VS2015 which was running perfectly good?

Any help is welcome! Thanks!

Comment: There is no .NET Core support (officially) in VS2015. Get started from an empty VS2017 project.

Comment: Oh. You are right. I forgot, that I started with a Core 1.X project and upgraded to the first supported VS2017 version by Core 2.0. Now I do have the latest VS2017 IDE and no publish-able result. I'll correct my question.

Comment: Please carefully update the question to match your situation. Then see if you happen to hit the same issue Microsoft created recently https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50567448/asp-net-core-deployment-persistent-errorcode-0x80004005-8000808c-on-win-20?noredirect=1#comment88149069_50567448

Comment: @LexLi updated.

Comment: Then you hit exactly the issue I linked I think.

Comment: @LexLi Tomorrow I'll try to download all the stuff from microsoft again, like in the other question. Otherwise I'll downgrade Core to 2.0.6 and try that.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks already. I'll let you know tomorrow if that helped.

Comment: You are writing "You probably used Framework Dependent Deployment, instead of Self Contained Deployment, which also amplifies the issue." in the other question. I already tried the Self-Contained-Solution on my webserver which fails with the exact same result.

Comment: Great! Installing "AspNetCore.2.0.8.RuntimePackageStore_x64.exe" from "https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/2.1.200-sdk-download.md" like you mentioned in the other question was the solution. I can't under stand why the did not officially release all installers in a version 2.0.8. Even the excuse "the versions are independent from each other" is in my opinion absolutely nonsense! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Seems like Microsoft just updated that stuff: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows

Comment: Yep. That's a move on the right direction.

Comment: Even better: Now 2.1 is out. ;-)