# asp.net core deployment persistent ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : 8000808c. on win 2012r2

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-8

I am having a persistent problem with ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : 8000808c. on win 2012r2
Deploying an updated app that uses:

```
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.8" />
```

I have installed

```
dotnet-runtime-2.0.7-win-x64.exe
AspNetCore.2.0.7.RuntimePackageStore_x64.exe
DotNetCore.2.0.7-WindowsHosting.exe
```

and rebooted the machine but the problem persists. I've deployed the same files to IIS (not IIS EXpress) on my windows 10 dev box and it works fine there.
Any ideas how to solve it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try installing hosting bundle https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/dotnet-runtime-2.0.7-windows-hosting-bundle-installer

Comment: I already said in my post I installed that, it is installed, I even installed it twice when it didn't fix it

Comment: Ok and you have app pool .NET CLR version set to “No Managed Code”? Also check in http handlers that you have also.net core handler showing up

Comment: yes, no managed code, handler mapping fine, worked before I upgrade to asp.net core 2.0.8

Comment: I've added images showing what I have said

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/2.1.200-sdk-download.md Scroll down to ".NET Core Runtime-only installation", and it seems that all your 2.0.7 installers were the old ones, while Microsoft almost silently refreshed all of them to include the 2.0.8 bits (what a crazy idea). The proof is that in your screen shot there is no "ASP.NET Runtime Core Package Store 2.0.8". You probably used Framework Dependent Deployment, instead of Self Contained Deployment, which also amplifies the issue.

Comment: @LexLi installing that solved the problem, post that answer and I will mark it as correct. It is ridiculous that the 2.0.8 Runtime Package Store is not even available on the main download page for .net core

Comment: Alternatively, See this if still struggling [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50713708/http-error-502-5-in-net-core-2-1-3-on-window-server-2016/52164675#52164675][1]

Comment: Alternatively See : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50713708/http-error-502-5-in-net-core-2-1-3-on-window-server-2016/52164675#52164675][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft made it not easy to find the relevant information.

Scroll down to ".NET Core Runtime-only installation" section in [release notes](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/2.1.200-sdk-download.md), and it seems that all your 2.0.7 installers were the old ones, while Microsoft almost silently refreshed all of them to include the 2.0.8 bits (what a crazy idea).

The proof is that in your screen shot there is no "ASP.NET Runtime Core Package Store 2.0.8". And you probably used Framework Dependent Deployment, instead of Self Contained Deployment, which also amplifies the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar error: ErrorCode = '0x80004005' : 8000808c.

I am using shared resources, and the package does not allow installation of .NET Core 2.1 SDK.

I had to change my publishing settings from Framework dependent to self-contained. That resolved the issue.

publish command:

```
dotnet publish --configuration Release -r win10-x64 -o "publish path" --self-contained true
```