# Why do I get HTTP Error 502.5 when installing .NET Core 2.1.3

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, iis-10, windows-server-2016

I installed .NET Core version 2.1.3 for my new computer running Windows Server 2016. I hosted it in IIS 10. But it gave me Error 502:

> HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure
>
> Common causes of this issue:
> The application process failed to start
> The application process started but then stopped
> The application process started but failed to listen on the configured port

This is my snippet for web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApplication1.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do really need to use web.config file or launchSetting .json ?

Comment: web.config file was generate automation in project

Comment: which template you are using to create your project?

Comment: I use "Web Application" and API, but both of them have same error

Comment: I think you are using wrong template create .net core

Comment: @AnkurShah: `launchSettings.json` is for IDE when starting with F5 or in debug mode. Its not used by webservers or the application itself

Comment: @Truc: Did you made sure the Hosting Bundle is installed on the Windows Server machine running IIS? https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows its usually included in the sdk but you rarely install the sdk on the server machines, just runtime + hosting bundle. See [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and [Host on IIS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x). The ANCM (ASP.NET Core Module) is part of the hosting bundle and required to run in iis

Comment: You might already have all bits installed, but it is time to follow this thread to enable more logging, https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/406

Comment: Try to use followign guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x
REMEMBER to restart iis with following commands: "net stop was /y" and "net start w3svc"

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the following:

1. .NET Core Hosting Bundle installed on the hosting server - [download from here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/dotnet-runtime-2.1.0-windows-hosting-bundle-installer)
2. Application Pool .NET CLR version set to "No Managed Code"
3. Ensure that the Application Pool Identity user has read permissions on the published folder.
   For details check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: Thank for your help. I replace  <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" ...> by <aspNetCore processPath="C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" ...> in web.config file and it worked

Answer (score 0):

The is a situation that if you use:

Env: Windows Server OS, .NET Core Hosting Bundle(including runtime), IIS, Asp.Net.Core

You could add a element as follows into {YourProject}.csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Ref: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/13542

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, For anyone who still struggling with .net core on IIS while running nuget package **Microsoft.Aspnetcore.all 2.1.3**, i will recommend to update the version to 'Latest Stable 2.1.301' as Microsoft has released the fix

Other version with IIS issue is **Microsoft.Aspnetcore.all 2.0.8** either upgrade to 'Latest Stable 2.1.301' or downgrade to 2.0.7.

No code or .csproj needed for changing needed.